# User rules to change Organic Groups User Role in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, organic-groups

We are trying to use Drupal's rules module to automatically change the Organic Groups member roles of group members when they respond or comment. Since there isn't a built-in way to do this within the OG module, we've tried to execute the 'og_role_grant' function from within the role.

This results in an fatal error, "Fatal error: Call to undefined function rules_data_selection_process()", on submission. We really need to figure out how to change these roles with rules. Help, we're desperate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Event**: When a comment is posted.

**Condition**: Select the node-type(s) related to your group(s).

**Action**: Assign user role

Comment: This works for general system roles. We are trying to set OG Roles--see above.